# Which preposition should come after 'tradition' in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

'' It's great to read about the exciting traditions in/of your countries! ''

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any exemplary sentences that would be helpful on Cambridge Dictionary, Lexico, and OALD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either would be acceptable. You can think of the traditions as existing **in** a country, or of belonging to it (**traditions of the country**).